# Integrate Fingerprint Scanner with Web Application

Tags: asp.net, fingerprint, hardware-interface

I want to Develop a web application, which accept fingerprint from client machine using any mouse with fingerprint scanner whose SDK supports ASP.NET. And this fingerprint will be cross verified at server side database to authenticate the user.

Is it possible?

Do we need to Develop from the scratch?

Can my Web Application be integrate with existing any "fingerprint logon application" for PC Security at Server side?

Comment: Check if javascript SDK support scanner solution helps you http://camsunit.com/application/html-based-fingerprint-scanner-for-website-authentication-and-attendance.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to develop a Browser plugin that will interact with the FringerPrint SDK... You may also have to develop different versions for the different Fingerprint scanners..

your Web application will then interact with the plugin...